# Fields marked HiddenFor not binding to Model in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have implemented an image upload child action form for an application. I have a strongly typed partial view.

```
public class ImageViewModel{
 public long ImageId{get;set;}
 public long OwnerId{get;set;}
 public string ImageName{get;set;}
 public string ImageDescription{get;set;}
 public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Razor code looks something like this:

```
<form action="UploadImage" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @Html.ValidationSummary()
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OwnerId)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImageId)
  @HtmlEditorFor(m=>m.ImageName)
  <input type="file" name="Files" id="file0" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

Here is the problem. When form is posted back, the model has uploaded file and ImageName value in it. But values that were bound using HiddenFor are missing.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadImage(ImageViewModel model)
{ ...}
```

I have checked HTML source. Hidden fields are rendered corrected with Id and names matching to property named of model. On post back I checked the raw request. Both hidden fields are carried in Form collection. But model binding is not setting the values of these fields in properties.
Is there something that I am missing about these hidden fields?

Thanks

Comment: Something else is wrong at your site. I've copied your code into an new MVC3 project and it works fine. The hidden fields transferred correctly also the uploaded file.